# Question on an integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, st.statistics, integration

I am reading [van de Vaart and Weller, Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes With Applications to Statistics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2545-2). And I am stuck in the proof of Theorem 2.6.7 on page 141.

For simplicity I restae the condition and my problem. Suppose $Q$ is a probability measure and $r>1$, $f,g,F$ are measurable functions and $Qf=\int f dQ$. Under the conditions below

1. $|f|\le F$
2. $F$ is integrable
3. $\int|f-g| dQ<2\int F dQ$

the proof of the theorem  said
$$
Q|f-g|^r\le Q|f-g|(2F)^{r-1}.
$$

I don't know how to derive this inequality. I tried to use $C_r$-inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
Q|f-g|^r&=\int|f-g||f-g|^{r-1}dQ
\\
&\le\int|f-g| \cdot 2^{r-2}(|f|^{r-1}+|g|^{r-1})dQ\\
&\le \int|f-g| \cdot 2^{r-2}F^{r-1}dQ+\int|f-g| \cdot 2^{r-2}|g|^{r-1}dQ.
\end{align}
$$
Hence I need to prove $\int|f-g| \cdot 2^{r-2}|g|^{r-1}dQ\le \int|f-g| \cdot 2^{r-2}F^{r-1}dQ$. From condition 1 and 3, it can be shown $Q|g|\le 3QF$ by the triangle inequality. However I cannot proceed further with the proof. I guess this should be obvious and easy, but I am really confused and have spent the whole day on this point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As written, it is just false. Take $r=2$, $f=0$, $F=1$ and $g$ in $L^1$ with norm $1$ but not in $L^2$. Most likely, some extra condition is missing.

Comment: It is unclear to me where you got your conditions 1--3 from. The function $g$ is not described/defined in the proof in the book at all. Apparently, they assumed that $|g|\le F$, and then the inequality is trivial.